# Error compiling minimal OpenCL example from LLVM documentation using clang

Tags: c++, linux, clang, opencl

My goal is to use C++ code in OpenCL kernels, which has been, as far as I can tell, supported by clang for quite a while.

I am using clang 15.0.6 on my Ubuntu machine 22.04 and am trying to compile the examples found in the LLVM documentation [here](https://releases.llvm.org/15.0.0/tools/clang/docs/UsersManual.html#opencl-features), the compiler is installed via the "official" script found [here](https://apt.llvm.org/).

`clang -v` shows:

```
Ubuntu clang version 15.0.6
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
```

Just like in the LLVM manual, I am trying to compile an empty kernel (`kernel void k(){}`) using this clang version, but it always throws a linker error:

```
$ clang test.cl
ld: error: undefined symbol: main
referenced by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o:(\_start)
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Surely I am missing something absolutely basic, but what it is?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: see https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-Guide/blob/main/chapters/os_tooling.md, looks like you're missing at least `-c` in your command line

Comment: I knew it had to be something trivial I was overlooking. Thank you so much, that worked perfectly! `clang` now compiles a binary from the kernel code, even with C++ features. I do have the follow-up issue that I am not able to load those binaries as OpenCL programs, but I'll make a separate post about that as soon as I have played around with it a bit more. Thanks again!